# iOS: pair a Bluetooth peripheral in my app, instead of using Settings

Tags: ios, bluetooth, pairing

**The Question**

I'm writing an app for a Bluetooth peripheral, and I want to pair the peripheral to the iPhone directly in my app, without asking the user to go the Settings app and do the pairing manually. I see the "Sony Headphones Connect" app does exactly that, and I want the same ability in my app. I can't find anything for doing this in Core Bluetooth. Any idea?

**Further Info**

Here's what the Sony app does. Initially the peripheral (a headphone) is not paired to the iPhone, as shown here:

[image]

I run the app and turn on the power of the headphone as instructed by the app:

[image]

After a while, the app finds and shows the headphone, and I tap it to register:

[image]

A dialog shows up and I tap again:

[image]

Finally the app reports that the headphone is registered.

[image]

Now in the Settings app I can see that the headphone is already paired and connected by the Sony app:

[image]

Comment: what type of device you want to connect?? BLE or Classic Bluetooth device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pairing with MFi Devices:**

You can import External Accessory framework and use `showBluetoothAccessoryPicker` to show **Select An Accessory** picker.

```
// Objective-C
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:nil];

// Swift        
EAAccessoryManager.shared().showBluetoothAccessoryPicker(withNameFilter: nil, completion: nil)
```

Note: do not forget to add the protocols needs to be supported in Info.plist

**Pairing with BLE Devices:**

You can import Core Bluetooth framework and use `scanForPeripherals` from `CBCentralManager` to get the list of devices and create your custom picker to show it in `didDiscover` delegate method.

For more detailed steps on scanning and connecting with BLE devices, Refer [here](https://www.appcoda.com/core-bluetooth/).

Comment: Not that this feature is currently broken for most apps. It broke when Apple introduced the new Scene-based lifecycle. Roll back to the classic one and it starts working again. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70823487/415982